# Timeline Waterfall View Missing

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I can't get to the waterfall view of my timeline. All I get is the flame chart. What am I missing? Does this need to be enabled somewhere?

[Timeline Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL3u6.png)

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean now. Looks like that's been removed. For anyone else wondering, this is the behavior @etune is asking about https://youtu.be/Y153mDckcgc?t=60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep it's gone.
if you'd like to see the activities happened in the selected range, use the "Event Log" on the bottom tabstrip.

[screenshot of Chrome DevTools showing timeline and event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMdxE.png)

it doesn't show events as waterfall but just a list, though.